# React-admin title not displaying on navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Seems like a simple thing. How do I put a title on the navbar? Here's my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { UserList } from './Users';
import { ItemList, ItemEdit, ItemCreate } from './Items';
import { ProductTypeList, ProductTypeEdit, ProductTypeCreate } from './ProductType'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
import dataProvider from './dataProvider';
import ItemIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ViewListRounded';
import ProductTypeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocalOffer';
import UserIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Group';
import authProvider from './authProvider'

const App = () => (
  <Admin
    dashboard={Dashboard}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    dataProvider={dataProvider} >
    <Resource
      name="items"
      list={ItemList}
      edit={ItemEdit}
      create={ItemCreate}
      icon={ItemIcon} />
    {<Resource
      name="productTypes"
      options={{ label: 'Product Types' }}
      list={ProductTypeList}
      edit={ProductTypeEdit}
      create={ProductTypeCreate}
      icon={ProductTypeIcon} />}
    <Resource
      name="users"
      list={UserList}
      icon={UserIcon} />
  </Admin >
);

export default App;
```

Running react-admin version 3.4.2. In the tutorial it shows "React Admin" as the title after adding the Dashboard. But after recreating a fresh app using npm create-react-app and going through the tutorial, I don't see a title in the navbar. Is this something that should be possible out of the box or do I need to create a custom navbar?

[image: My app without a title in navbar]

Comment: probably the title or name attribute https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html

Comment: I did add the title attribute to App but nothing changed. Thanks though.

Comment: why App? Add it to `<Admin />` just like you did `resources`

Comment: Sorry. I meant <Admin /> not App. However, you sparked an idea when you said "just like you did resources". So I tried adding <Title /> and it worked. See my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Train (above) led me to think of the  component. I imported it and used it within  and set title="My Title" and it did show in the navbar. Maybe I misread the docs, but I don't remember seeing anything about , just the title= attribute of , like so:

```
  <Admin
    // layout={CustomLayout}
    dashboard={Dashboard}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    dataProvider={dataProvider} >
    <Title title="g3tools Admin" />
    <Resource
      name="items"
      list={ItemList}
      edit={ItemEdit}
      create={ItemCreate}
      icon={ItemIcon} />
```

But, thankfully, it gets me to the next step: Now the title shows up in the navbar but when I choose a resource from the left menu, the resource name appends to the title.

[image]

Any suggestions on how to avoid the resource title cramming into the admin title? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Options would be: a) Dynamically ad a space or dash after title when resource title is displayed, or b) don't display the resource title (how would I do that?)

I think ultimately, I'd rather have a breadcrumb or show the resource title in the center of the navbar, but maybe I'll need a custom navbar for that?? Any guidance is welcome.

UPDATE:
I see in [the docs for Customizing the AppBar](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html) how to not show the individual resource page title: Just remove the id="react-admin-title" from the  component and then add text to the element:

```
<AppBar {...props}>
  <Typography
    variant="h6"
    color="inherit"
    className={classes.title}
  >g3tools Admin</Typography>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing Dan, you answered your own question. joy of learning right :)

Comment: Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Title' in '/home/gabi/Bureau/mlp_analysis_ui/src'

Answer (score 1):

take a look in the [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#title), try this

```
<Admin
   // add the title prop below
   title="my page title"
   dashboard={Dashboard}
   authProvider={authProvider}
   dataProvider={dataProvider} >
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Thanks. Thought it work too. But, I see nothing showing up in the navbar.  Still blank.